# invest in ETH using the POS - what am i missing?

Tags: proof-of-stake, mining-pools

I'm wondering if i can invest in ETH using the POS system. I have the following idea:

1. Get a computer (regular one no special GPU) to be up 24\7
2. Connect to a staking pool like RocketPool or similar
3. Buy ETH say 1 ETH ..
4. Stake the 1 ETH in the pool
5. If i understand correctly this means i will get around 0.9 rETH on every reward

All this seems like a very good investment deal. What am I missing here ? Can I loose money like this ? (not by ETH loosing value, i mean by losing ETH coins)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have misunderstood the reward rate.

The current Eth2 reward rate seems to be around 4,8%. This means you get 4,8% yearly interest for your stake. https://ethereumprice.org/eth-2-calculator/

You can either stake through a service which does everything for you (a centralized service or a more decentralized one like Rocketpool) or run your own validator node, which is not a trivial task. Staking services of course take a small fee for the service.

Comment: so the reward is annual and not per block ? this is the misunderstanding ?

Comment: 4,8% in a year, yes.